# How to add GridView Row to datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a gridview with headercheckboxes and childcheckboxes.When headercheckbox is clicked child checkboxes will automatically be checked.For this i've used javascript named 'checked' and its working fine..

My problem is i want to add all the checked child items to a datatable,simultaneously when i check header checkbox.
Also when only child checkbox is clicked that row should only be added to datatable..
This is because  only checked items need to to to database...

How can i achieve this ???

Comment: An appropriate tag for which of the .NET web technologies you're using would help.

Answer (score 1):

If your gridview is already populated (from any source) and you want to copy the it's values to a DataTable you can use this part of the code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in YourGridView.Rows)
             {
                 DataRow datarw;
                 datarw = dt.NewRow();
                 for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                 {
                     datarw[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
                 }


                 dt.Rows.Add(datarw);
         }
```

[This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15070/GridView-to-a-DataTable) can make you understand-

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve through your DB also. ..

Arrange your DB according to main_srl_no and srl_no like headerchkbox and childchkbox respectively...

It is simple.... I implemented in my sys.
I will works fine..

Comment: I dun hv rihght nw... Provide main serial no and serial no to checkbox content or item template ... like that Question No and Sub Question NO ...

Alter your table just provide this no...Y u r gng on rough road....